# Facebook API BUG type=event

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I run in Graph API Explorer:

```
search?type=event&q=The Porterhouse
```

Which was working up to a few days ago, I receive:

```
{

"data": [

        ]
}
```

Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Post the whole code corresponding to your problem . Place the full js part where you are calling the graph api

Comment: does this help?    Seems like problem is on the FB side -- their api interface (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) returns empty array by the default search query (search?type=event&q=dublin)  I am testing it here.............https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.1

Comment: `GET/2.5/me?fields=id,name` like this

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/916199865137566/

Comment: Not working for me either using `v2.10` Searching for pages works fine, For events I cannot get data back.